# TreasuryDirect.Gov Tax Withholding

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, treasury

Anyone know where in treasurydirect.gov website we setup tax withholding for interest accrued owning T-Bills and Notes?

[image: From TreasuryDirect Website]

Answer (score 3):

It took a few clicks to find it.

1. Go to the "manage direct" tab
2. On the left hand side of the page will be an "Update my personal information" link. After you click this link you will probably have to answer one of your security questions.
3. At the bottom of the page is where you set the withholding amount.
4. Click submit.